# ViewModel with dynamic elements

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, deserialization, viewmodel

I need to receive the next JSON in .NET

```
"currentData": 
{ 
  "Name": {"system": "wfdss", "canWrite": true }, 
  "DiscoveryDateTime": { "system": "wfdss", "canWrite": true },
  "Code": { "system": "code", "canWrite": false }, 
   ... 
}
```

This elements are dynamics, it doesn't have default elements, so, how can I define a class doing that following next model:

```
public class currentData
{
    //TODO
    //<Data Element Name>: { 
    //data element system: <STRING of system>, 
    //the last system to update data element canWrite: <Boolean> 
    //true if requesting system may edit data element (based on ADS),    otherwise false. }, ...
    public List<Property> property { get; set; }
}

public class Property
{
    public string system { get; set; }
    public string canWrite { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can u please post the variation you can get in the JSON

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the JSON?

Comment: Have you thought about using `dynamic`?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to post dynamic structured Json to controller i have a bad news for you - **you can't map it automattically in MVC**. MVC model binding mechanism work only with stronly typed collecions - **you must know structure**.

One of the options that i can suggest you if use `FormCollection` and manually get values from it:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JsonAction(FormCollection collection)
{
    string CurrentDataNameSystem = collection["currentData.Name.system"];
    // and so on...
    return Json(null);
}
```

Another option is to pass you dynamic json as string and then manually desirialize it:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult JsonAction(string json)
{
    //You probably want to try desirialize it to many different types you can wrap it with try catch 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourObjectType>(jsonString);
    return Json(null);
}
```

Anyway my point is - you shouldn't mess with dynamic json unless you really need it in MVC.

I suggest you to creage object type that contain all the passible fields but make it all nullable so you can pass your Json and it will be mapped with Model binding MVC mechanism but some fields will be `null`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the type format you are getting is an Object with a Dictionary.
So i think you need to Deserialize your Data into this.

```
    public class ContainerObject
    {
        public Dictionary<String,Property> currentData { get; set; }
    }
```